# Spring Interface Driven Controllers usage

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns

I used to write @RestControllers without interface, but suddenly saw article https://www.baeldung.com/spring-interface-driven-controllers, describing such pattern *Interface Driven Controllers*. So the question is: why its need to create controllers with special interface per controller with annotated methods, for example @GetMapping, @RequestBody, @PathVariable etc. at all? It seems more complicated without any profit for me.

Comment: convention is controllers without interfaces but SO is not the place to ask for best practices as those are opinionated and situation-dependent

Comment: Why not? Here are special tag for it-"design-patterns". Where else i can ask it? Can you please provide as many info as you know about various situation about usage of such interfaces?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142353/why-is-asking-a-question-on-best-practice-a-bad-thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In article is perfectly explained
you can implement one interface with same methods in two controllers:

```
@RequestMapping("/oldversioncontroller/book")
public class BookOldController implements BookOperations {...}

@RequestMapping("/newversioncontroller/book")
public class BookNewController implements BookOperations {...}
```

Comment: Seems not to be a regular practice for all controllers, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Swagger annotations it's very likely that your controller might be hard to read. Using interfaces you can pass all this annotations to the interface and maintain readability in the controller implementation.